# Access SQL - Query (Show specific selections in query)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a database where the user can track work being conducted on a machine. So in my database I have two tables;

TblLocations

1. LocationNames

TblUptimes

1. Location (Ref to TblLocations)
2. Date
3. QuantityProduced

To make life easier for the user, each day they will enter into a form with a textbox which they enter todays date, a textbox so they can enter a quantity of items produced.

I want a listbox which shows all the machines. The user selects the machine and when they enter the quantity and click the button it adds this information to the TblUptimes table.

My question here is as a fail safe measure, when the user inputs the data for say machine1 on Monday, I want this to disappear from the list as it now has a record for Monday. However if the user changes the date to Tuesday, then the machine will appear in the list until the user as added a record for that day.

My idea was within the query for the listbox is that it would reference the tbluptimes and have a criteria on the date along the lines of  "is not [Forms]![frmMachineUptimes]![TEXTDate]". I know this code is not right but I hope you understand what it is I am looking for.

Comment: Please follow whichever naming convention makes most sense to you and your team. If you choose to label every procedure "proc..." that is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL answer because I'm much more familiar in that realm, though the queries should be almost exactly the same so apologies if it isn't a direct copy paste solution, but it should be close.

I didn't include this because I don't know the access syntax, but strip off times from your dates when comparing to be sure to not filter out any results on accident.

Without "Distinct" you would get a lot of the same names back, hoping that this is available in Access...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TblLocations.LocationNames
FROM TblLocations 
    LEFT JOIN TblUptimes ON TblLocations.LocationNames = TblUptimes.Location
WHERE TblUptimes.Date <> @inputDate
```

Comment: . . SQL Server and MS Access are *not* "almost exactly the same".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've had plenty of MS Access queries I've had to move over into a SQL Server environment to be used in newer versions of software and more times than not the most I have to do is reformat some date functions... Am I missing something here? In almost all of these cases they were practically working immediately

Comment: The basic query language/syntax is very close (as close as it is among, say, MySQL and MSSQL, for example).  I think Gordon's talking about features and functionality.

Comment: @jleach yes, i realized I wasn't clear in my initial wording, I revised it to reflect what I meant. I didn't mean the two languages behave the same most of the time, I just meant that in this particular instance, the two queries should be almost exactly the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff as i eluded to, I was talking in the case of the logic used in THIS query I provided, not the entire languages as a whole. Don't be so quick to jump down someones throat.